# Are there any performance costs of using JSLINQ

Tags: javascript, linq, jslinq

When you read this question, please do not answer with "memory is cheap" or yada yada.

I was wondering; and it would save me the time and thus i'd be very grateful, if anyone had timed the difference between a very raw approach to querying javascript arrays including memory usage, versus using LINQ.

An application I am building is getting quite large on memory and yet some tool like JSLINQ would be very beneficial to me, I would like to be able to scientifically measure the pros and cons of performance using JSLINQ rather than brawl through my javascript arrays myself to save the teenytiniest of performance.

If there are no responses, I of course will find this out myself, it would be a nice little experiment for future users.

My javascript object arrays range from generating tables of users where something = something and orderby yada yada... to doing joins on users with profiles. I am trying to find out if it's better to return datasets and then refine snippets of that data with javascript, or continuously call server side pages using ajax. Regardless of which I choose, it's the performance hit i'm most interested in.

JSLINQ is looking very tempting because it uses a familiar technique to me, to query data... Alas, I simply cannot use it if it adds a significant performance loss... This I would imagine, will need to be measured by execution time on array sorting and fetching minus the time it takes for ajax calls to return responses.

P.S, if you do not have any figures to produce, no worries at all. Over the next few days I will be experimenting this myself, I was hoping to save some time... And I understand that this question may be, at best, quite coarse.

http://jslinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: If you don't give any specifics then people will assume you are doing CRUD and give memory is cheap answers. For example there is huge relative performance cost in using AngularJS, but yet it usually doesn't matter because of the nature of the applications it is aimed at.

Comment: I have given an example, I have a large application. I will be using JSLINQ or raw javascript to do certain queries on my javascript objects... Is there a significant performance hit; can it be measured? :) ... ALAS, I have added a small excerpt at the end!

Comment: You said _"was wondering...if anyone had timed the difference between a very raw approach to querying javascript arrays...versus using LINQ."_ and THEN you said _"am trying to find out if it's better to return datasets and then refine snippets of that data with javascript, or continuously call server side pages using ajax"_  This sounds like two different questions.  Is it me?

Comment: Try not to treat it as 2. If someone has some data behind performance, they'd quite easily post it here. Either those people have not found this post, or no one has it. I will keep this post updated with my findings if that is the case, It is a requirement that I quantify using JSLINQ with real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are the only one that can answer this question.

While anyone can run memory comparisons of some specific test with "pure" JS vs JSLinq, those comparisons would be relevant to the specific data set and JSLinq methods being tested.  Results in that specific test may, or likely, won't translate to your different situation.

If this is a critical part of your application, then write it both ways and then compare.  Then write up your results somewhere to benefit others, which can't answer the question "is JSLinq always better?" but can answer "Is JSLinq better in this specific situation?"